# Data is not being distributed among Tensorflow Workers

Tags: tensor, tensorflow

I have written a distributed TensorFlow program with 1 ps job and 2 worker jobs. I was expecting the data batches to be distributed among workers but it don't seem to be the case. I see that only one worker (task=0) is doing all the work while the other one is idle. Could you please help me find the issue with this program:

```
    import math
    import tensorflow as tf
    from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data

    # Flags for defining the tf.train.ClusterSpec
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("master_hosts", "oser502110:2222",
                           "Comma-separated list of hostname:port pairs")

    # Flags for defining the tf.train.Server
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "One of 'ps', 'worker'")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("hidden_units", 100,
                            "Number of units in the hidden layer of the NN")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("data_dir", "/tmp/mnist-data",
                           "Directory for storing mnist data")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("batch_size", 100, "Training batch size")

    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_grpc_url", None,
                    "Worker GRPC URL")

    FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

    IMAGE_PIXELS = 28

def main(_):
    ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
    worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
    master_hosts = FLAGS.master_hosts.split(",")


    cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps": ps_hosts, "worker": worker_hosts})

    # Create and start a server for the local task.
    server = tf.train.Server(cluster,
                             job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                             task_index=FLAGS.task_index)

    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
        server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

        is_chief = (FLAGS.task_index == 0)
        if is_chief: tf.reset_default_graph()


# Assigns ops to the local worker by default.
        with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
                worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index,
                cluster=cluster)):

            # Variables of the hidden layer
            hid_w = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([IMAGE_PIXELS * IMAGE_PIXELS, FLAGS.hidden_units],
                                    stddev=1.0 / IMAGE_PIXELS), name="hid_w")
            hid_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([FLAGS.hidden_units]), name="hid_b")

            # Variables of the softmax layer
            sm_w = tf.Variable(
                tf.truncated_normal([FLAGS.hidden_units, 10],
                                    stddev=1.0 / math.sqrt(FLAGS.hidden_units)),
                name="sm_w")
            sm_b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]), name="sm_b")

            x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, IMAGE_PIXELS * IMAGE_PIXELS])
            y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 10])

            hid_lin = tf.nn.xw_plus_b(x, hid_w, hid_b)
            hid = tf.nn.relu(hid_lin)

            y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.nn.xw_plus_b(hid, sm_w, sm_b))
            loss = -tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(tf.clip_by_value(y, 1e-10, 1.0)))

            global_step = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False)

            train_op = tf.train.AdagradOptimizer(0.01).minimize(
                loss, global_step=global_step)

            saver = tf.train.Saver()
            #summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
            init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

        # Create a "supervisor", which oversees the training process.
        sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=is_chief,
                                 logdir="/tmp/train_logs",
                                 init_op=init_op,
                                 recovery_wait_secs=1,
                                 saver=saver,
                                 global_step=global_step,
                                 save_model_secs=600)
        if is_chief:
            print("Worker %d: Initializing session..." % FLAGS.task_index)
        else:
            print("Worker %d: Waiting for session to be initialized..." % FLAGS.task_index)

        mnist = input_data.read_data_sets(FLAGS.data_dir, one_hot=True)

        sess_config = tf.ConfigProto(allow_soft_placement=True, log_device_placement=True,
                                     device_filters=["/job:ps", "/job:worker/task:%d" % FLAGS.task_index])


        # The supervisor takes care of session initialization, restoring from
        # a checkpoint, and closing when done or an error occurs.
        with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target, config=sess_config) as sess:
            print("Worker %d: Session initialization complete." % FLAGS.task_index)
            # Loop until the supervisor shuts down or 1000000 steps have completed.
            step = 0
            while not sv.should_stop() and step < 1000000:
                # Run a training step asynchronously.
                # See `tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer` for additional details on how to
                # perform *synchronous* training.

                batch_xs, batch_ys = mnist.train.next_batch(FLAGS.batch_size)
                print("FETCHING NEXT BATCH %d" % FLAGS.batch_size)
                train_feed = {x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}

                _, step = sess.run([train_op, global_step], feed_dict=train_feed)
                if step % 100 == 0:
                    print("Done step %d" % step)

        # Ask for all the services to stop.
        sv.stop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

and here are the logs from the workers with task=0:

2017-06-20 04:50:58.405431: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] Adagrad/value: (Const)/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 truncated_normal/stddev: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 
2017-06-20 04:50:58.405456: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/stddev: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 truncated_normal/mean: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 
2017-06-20 04:50:58.405481: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/mean: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 truncated_normal/shape: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 
2017-06-20 04:50:58.405506: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/shape: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0 Worker 0: Session initialization complete. 
FETCHING NEXT BATCH 500 
FETCHING NEXT BATCH 500 
FETCHING NEXT BATCH 500 
FETCHING NEXT BATCH 500 
FETCHING NEXT BATCH 500 
Done step 408800 
... 
...

but from worker 2 (task=1) the logs looks like:

2017-06-20 04:51:07.288600: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] zeros: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 Adagrad/value: (Const): /job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 
 
2017-06-20 04:51:07.288614: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] Adagrad/value: (Const)/job:ps/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0 truncated_normal/stddev: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 
2017-06-20 04:51:07.288639: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/stddev: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 truncated_normal/mean: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 
2017-06-20 04:51:07.288664: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/mean: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 truncated_normal/shape: (Const): /job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0 2017-06-20 04:51:07.288689: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/simple_placer.cc:841] truncated_normal/shape: (Const)/job:worker/replica:0/task:1/gpu:0

I was expecting similar logs from both the workers. Please help me understand this. Looking forward to your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually separate out the data for each worker.

```
# Get the subset of data for this worker 

mnist = input_data.read_data_sets('/tmp/mnist_temp', one_hot=True)
num_old = mnist.train._num_examples
ids = list(range(task_index, mnist.train._num_examples, num_workers))
mnist.train._images = mnist.train._images[ids,]
mnist.train._labels = mnist.train._labels[ids,]
mnist.train._num_examples = mnist.train._images.shape[0]

print("subset of training examples ", mnist.train._num_examples,"/",num_old)
```